# Split time series data into Train Test and Valid sets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I'm working on a project in which I have combined 2 datasets if time series (e.g D1, D2). `D1` was with the `5-minutes` interval and `D2` was for the `1-minute` interval, so I transformed the `D1` to 1-minute interval and combine with the `D2`. Now I want to split this new dataset `D1D2` into train, test and valid sets on the base of these conditions:

> **Note:** I have searched a lot and try to find a solution for my problem but couldn't any answer fit to my question, so don't mark this as duplicate, please!

1. The valid set should be 60 values from the end of the dataset.
2. Then, the test set should be the most recent values till to the
   `valid set`
3. Then, I will have the train set with the remaining data.

Here's how I'm doing the split now:

```
def split_train_test(dataset, train_size, test_size):
    train = dataset[:train_size, :]
    test = dataset[test_size:, :]
    # split into input and outputs
    train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
    test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
    # reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
    train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
    test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
    print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape)
    return train, test, train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y
```

But now I need to convert into train, test and split on the base of the above conditions?

How can I do that? and also is it the right way to split time-series datasets?

Comment: You can select rows counting reverse: `train_df = df[:-60, :]`

Comment: so, it will give me the last 60 records for `valid set` but how can I can split the remaining records to `train and test`?

Comment: I have mentioned 3 conditions above in the question.

Comment: What does `Then, the test set should be the most recent values till to the valid set` mean?

Comment: it means, we take the last 60 values in the `valid set` that's I mean we have to take the recent values as the `test set` by leaving the last 60 records of the dataset.

Comment: If you have a 500 rows dataset, what would be the split ratio for all of them? Valid test has to be **60** always? What would be `latest values` for test?

Comment: I think that, after removing the last 60 records into validation set, the rest of the data can be split as 63%(train ) and remaining into test.

Comment: @pissall can you update your answer accordingly? please!

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
valid_set = dataset.iloc[-60:, :]
test_set = dataset.iloc[-120:-60]
train_set = dataset.iloc[:-120]
```

to generalize:

```py
def split_train_test(dataset, validation_size):
    valid = dataset.iloc[-validation_size:, :]
    train_test = dataset.iloc[:-validation_size)]

    train_length = int(0.63 * len(train_test))

    # split into input and outputs
    train_X, train_y = train_test.iloc[:train_length, :-1], train_test.iloc[:train_length, -1]
    test_X, test_y = train_test.iloc[train_length:, :-1], train_test.iloc[train_length:, -1]
    valid_X, valid_y = valid.iloc[:, :-1], valid.iloc[:, -1]

    return train_test, valid, train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, valid_X, valid_y
```

You can pass the % split rati into the function as a parameter rather than hardcoding it into the function as I have.